# Is there ever a time when you would want to be in a detached head state?

Tags: git

Basically what the title states. I'm aware of what detached HEAD state is and how you get to one and how to checkout of it. But I was curious if there was a direct use case to have a detached HEAD.

Possibly better question: What is a real life dev scenario where you would want to checkout to a specific commit SHA, but not check it out into a branch.

Comment: When you're troubleshooting, doing a bisect (literally, or manually), etc.

Comment: so basically just for investigative purposes but no real intentions to change any code at the current time?

Comment: You can't change code in git history.  You could start a new branch from an arbitrary commit if you want.

Comment: right, hence being in the detached state yeah?

Comment: Not being able to modify history has nothing to do with being detached. Maybe you meant something else?

Comment: yeah, i meant making new commits against the current commit in a detached head state

Comment: The "detached HEAD" mode is also used internally by various Git operations, including both `git filter-branch` and `git rebase`. It's useful for manipulating branches while not standing on the branches you're manipulating—think of it as sawing off tree limbs; you don't want to be *on* them while you're doing that. :-)

Comment: @AndrewKim, ...I sometimes have intentionally done that (committing against a detached-head state, with the intent of later cherry-picking from, merging from, diffing against, or doing a soft-reset to the resulting committish)... but those tend to be rare, experts-only scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bisecting, or any other kind of "time travel" debugging will put you in this state.  It's useful because you can find out what your app looked like at a certain point in time (commit).

Answer (score 3):

When you're trying to find where in history a bug was introduced.

Or

When you're trying to reproduce the behavior of a previous build, to diagnose an issue reported by a client/customer whose working version is not a branch tip in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

[Submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-checkout) are almost always in detached HEAD state.